# ActiveRecord select attributes without AR objects

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table with MANY rows, I need just the IDs of certain rows.
The slow way is to call

```
SomeARClass.find(:all, :conditions => {:foo => true}, :select => :id)
```

This returns AR Objects...

Is there a way to call a select on a class and have it return a plain old ruby data structure. Something like this:

```
SomeARClass.select(:id, :conditions => {:foo => true})
-> [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql)
```

or

```
SomeARClass.connection.select_all(sql)
```

This is what you want to use.  It returns an array of hashes.  It should be used sparingly though.  Hand coded sql is what ActiveRecord was built to replace.  I only use in in really performance critical areas where constructing and returning AR objects is too slow.

Comment: use SomeARClass.pluck(:attribute) instead.

Answer (score 4):

The [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) method is exactly what you want, without compromising the SQL bad practice:

```
SomeARClass.where(:foo => true).pluck(:id)
```

I believe this should be the selected answer!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is anything like `SomeARClass.select(:id, :conditions => {:foo => true})`
 but you have two options

1. ```
   SomeARClass.find(:all, :conditions => {:foo => true}, :select => :id).map(&:id)
   #=> [1,2,3,4]
   ```
2. ```
   id_hash = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all('select id from tablename')
   #=>  [{"id"=>"1"}, {"id"=>"2"}, {"id"=>"3"}, {"id"=>"4"}]

   id_hash.map(&:values).flatten
   #=>  ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
   ```

The second option returns only a hash and not Active record objects but it does looks a bit hackish.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

- Use [`.ids`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ids) to fetch only ids
- Use [`pluck`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) to fetch ONLY some columns, but values will be PARSED by Active Record
- Use [`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_all) to fetch UNPARSED values.

**Notes:**

There is small difference between `pluck` and `select_all`:

If you `pluck` data - ActiveRecord map data to Ruby objects, like Dates, Enums, 
Models, etc, and it could be different than you expect.

You can notice that the result below is a string:

```
2.5.1 :001 > ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("select created_at from some_ar_class where id = 1 limit 1").rows.first
   (0.6ms)  select created_at from some_ar_classes where id = 1 limit 1
 => ["2018-10-01 01:12:31.758161"]
```

While `pluck` return Dates

```
2.5.1 :002 > SomeARClass.where(id: 1).pluck(:created_at).first.class
   (0.4ms)  SELECT "some_ar_classes"."created_at" FROM "some_ar_classes" WHERE "some_ar_classes"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]
 => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

The same happens with Enums(int in database, but :symbols in Ruby)

And all this parsing/mapping operations also takes time. It's not a lot, but still.  So if you asking for the most fast way to fetch data - its definitely raw sql query with `connection.select_all`, but there are very small situations when you can get some significant performance increase on that.

**So my recommendation is using `pluck`.**